# kendo grid with more than one datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design, kendo-grid

I'm having 3 radio buttons.I have 3 different stored procedures that is called for 3 different radio buttons.
Example:
I have a kendo grid. I want the results to be displayed in the same grid for all 3 radiobutton selection.
FindCustomer_Result is my stored procedure to call the customers details.
Now if i select the second radiobutton i want resources Stored procedure details to display.
Please help.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<proj.Data.FindCustomer_Result>()
            .Name("CustomerSearch")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Visible(false);
                columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Width(130);
                columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Address1).Width(150);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
          //call getcustomer to fetch details of customer
         .Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer")
                                .Data("functiontobind"))
                .ServerOperation(false)
            )
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Filterable()
            .RowAction(row => row.HtmlAttributes.Add("data-id", row.DataItem.ID))
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel wich contains your three RadioButtons:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool Radio1 {get;set;}
    public bool Radio2 {get;set;}
    public bool Radio3 {get;set;}
}
```

Then fill the ViewModel in your Controller (Customer) and specified Action (GetCustomer)

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    .......
    public ActionResult GetCustomer([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest gridRequest)
    {
        IList<MyViewModel> myViewModels = new List<MyViewModel>();
        //fill ViewModels here from stored Procedures
        return Json(myViewModels.ToDataSourceResult(gridRequest));
    }
    ........
}
```

Then change your view Code as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
        .Name("CustomerSearch")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Radio1).Width(130);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Radio2).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Radio3).Width(150);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
      //call getcustomer to fetch details of customer
     .Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer")
                            .Data("functiontobind"))
            .ServerOperation(false)
        )
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .RowAction(row => row.HtmlAttributes.Add("data-id", row.DataItem.ID))
        )
```

Comment: thankyou @Ping for the earlier response.
I still dont understand how the three views can be called for the same grid,Cab you please elaborate the ""//fill ViewModels here from stored Procedures"" part .